# Remove titlebar of QMessageBox when use static method QMessageBox::information()?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qtstylesheets, qmessagebox

To show a message box I use this code:

```
int ret = QMessageBox::question(this,"Title","Stupid code",QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
```

Everything works as expected, but now, I want to remove the title bar of the message box.
How can I achieve this?

I don't want to use:

```
QMessageBox msgBox("Title" , "Stupid code", QMessageBox::Question, QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No, this, Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
msgBox.exec();
```

Comment: Did you try QMessageBox msgBox("" , "Stupid code", QMessageBox::Question, QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No, this, Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

Comment: I dont want to do that (I said in the p/s). @_@

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to use the method suggested by @Arun?

Comment: Everyone in our project use the static api. But now we want to decorate the window. If use @Arun's suggestion, we need to change a lot of line code @_@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a wrapper function by creating your own `XMessageBox` class with a static member function `question()`, accepting the same arguments as `QMessageBox::question()`. In your wrapper function, create a `QMessageBox` object with the arguments given to your function and in addition, the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag, call `exec()` and pass on the return value. This way you only need to search and replace all occurrences of `QMessageBox::question` with `XMessageBox::question` in your code.

If you want more flexibility you can make your `question()` function accept an additional argument of type `Qt::WindowFlags` and pass this on to the `QMessageBox` constructor.

The only alternative that will let you do what you want without changing any of your code would be to change the Qt code (qmessagebox.cpp) and recompile Qt.